# Ubuntu font is wrong in Kubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu-font-family

After upgrading from Kubuntu 12.04 to Kubuntu 12.10, I have a peculiar and very specific font problem.  My default font all along has been Ubuntu 11.  Now it shows up as bolded -- that is, Ubuntu Bold 11 and Ubuntu Regular 11 look exactly the same.  I don't see this for any other size of the Ubuntu font--for Ubuntu 10 and Ubuntu 12, for instance, the regular font is thinner than the bold font, as it should be.

I've reinstalled the **ttf-ubuntu-font-family** package, but that hasn't made any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Kubuntu use their own package for Ubuntu font now ...
Download correct files from [Ubuntu Font Family](http://font.ubuntu.com/), remove broken packages, and reinstall.

Other version that's some theme in your Kubuntu installation has regular font style and disabled interface logic related to change this style.
If yes, then I think near future they planned to fix this. Not exactly, subjectively.